# Limit of of $\cos(kt+kux)$ as $k\rightarrow 0$

Tags: trigonometry, physics

What would be limit of $$\cos(kt+kux)$$ as $k\to0$, where $$k=2\sqrt{1-a^{2}}$$ $$u=b\left(6-k^{2}\right)$$ and $a$ and $b$ are real numbers?

The answer that I have found in the book is $$\lim_{k\rightarrow 0}\cos(kt+kux)=(t+6xb)^{2}$$

I have tried it many times, but can't do it. Can anyone help solve it or give a hint?

Comment: Please mention the constants in the question .

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are constants

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are constants

Comment: What about $t$ and $x$ ?

Comment: $t$ and $x$ are variables

Comment: Why do you think the answer in the book is correct? The answer should be $1-\sqrt{1-a^2}(t+6xb)^2$

Comment: @Andrei, May b you are right, can you add few steps to get the answer as mentioned above.

Comment: @Andrei, May b you are right, can you add few steps to get the answer as mentioned above.

Comment: Note that I forgot to square the square root. And there is a factor of $2$ as well then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small $z$ $\cos(z)\approx1-\frac{z^2}{2}$. For small $k$, $u\approx 6b$. Then $$\cos(k(x+6bt))\approx 1-\frac{k^2}{2}(t+6xb)^2$$